# Jenkins failure build: Internal Error: Unhandled kpi type with performance plugin

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm running Jenkins with the Performance Plugin. 
I have a multiple JMeter jmx scripts which run on jenkins and I'm trying to add this one. But the build is always failing. With this message

```
 Internal Error: Unhandled kpi type: <type 'long'>
```

bzt installation is also done.
I can't seem to find much info about this on google. Any help?

After the shutdown I'm getting this:

```
19:42:27 INFO: Shutting down...
19:42:27 INFO: Post-processing...
19:42:29 INFO: Test duration: 0:47:04
19:42:29 INFO: Samples count: 3200, 3.25% failures
19:42:29 INFO: Average times: total 4.369, latency 0.000, connect 0.000
19:42:29 INFO: Percentiles:
+---------------+---------------+
| Percentile, % | Resp. Time, s |
+---------------+---------------+
|           0.0 |         0.258 |
|          50.0 |         3.251 |
|          90.0 |         8.799 |
|          95.0 |        14.375 |
|          99.0 |        24.239 |
|          99.9 |        30.031 |
|         100.0 |        35.743 |
+---------------+---------------+
19:42:29 INFO: Request label stats:
+----------------------+--------+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| label                | status |   succ | avg_rt | error                                                               |
+----------------------+--------+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Click_ToonSelectie   |  FAIL  | 94.00% |  4.984 | Number of samples in transaction : 4, number of failing samples : 1 |
|                      |        |        |        | Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect            |
|                      |        |        |        | Not Modified                                                        |
| FilterBrand          |  FAIL  | 99.00% |  0.832 | Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 1 |
| LoadFilterPage       |  FAIL  | 96.00% |  6.306 | Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect            |
|                      |        |        |        | Number of samples in transaction : 3, number of failing samples : 1 |
| OpenRandomCarDetails |  FAIL  | 96.00% |  5.355 | Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 1 |
|                      |        |        |        | Moved Permanently                                                   |
+----------------------+--------+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
19:42:29 INFO: Request label stats:
+----------------------+--------+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| label                | status |   succ | avg_rt | error                                                               |
+----------------------+--------+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Click_ToonSelectie   |  FAIL  | 94.00% |  4.984 | Number of samples in transaction : 4, number of failing samples : 1 |
|                      |        |        |        | Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect            |
|                      |        |        |        | Not Modified                                                        |
| FilterBrand          |  FAIL  | 99.00% |  0.832 | Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 1 |
| LoadFilterPage       |  FAIL  | 96.00% |  6.306 | Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect            |
|                      |        |        |        | Number of samples in transaction : 3, number of failing samples : 1 |
| OpenRandomCarDetails |  FAIL  | 96.00% |  5.355 | Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 1 |
|                      |        |        |        | Moved Permanently                                                   |
+----------------------+--------+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
19:42:29 INFO: Dumping final status as XML: aggregate-results.xml
19:42:29 ERROR: Internal Error: Unhandled kpi type: <type 'long'>
19:42:29 INFO: Artifacts dir: C:\Users\Kristof\.jenkins\workspace\ACC-Tweedehands\2018-07-19_18-55-13.298000
19:42:29 WARNING: Done performing with code: 1
Build step 'Run Performance Test' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

First 2 lines of JTL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testResults version="1.2">
```

Comment: We cannot help without seeing at least first 2 lines of your .jtl results file

Comment: @DmitriT added them!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Taurus tool my expectation is that you should be providing `kpi.jtl` CSV file instead of .jtl results file in XML format.

I cannot reproduce your issue using normal `kpi.jtl` results file from Taurus and latest [Performance Plugin version 3.10](https://plugins.jenkins.io/performance)

I neither can reproduce your issue, my output is totally different:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building on master in workspace /Users/jenkins/Projects/temp/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/Taurus
Performance: Recording JMeterCsv reports '/Users/jenkins/Projects/temp/Jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Taurus/builds/2/temp/kpi.jtl'
Performance: Parsing JMeter report file '/Users/jenkins/Projects/temp/Jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Taurus/builds/2/performance-reports/JMeterCSV/kpi.jtl'.
Performance: No threshold configured for making the test unstable
Performance: No threshold configured for making the test failure
Performance: File kpi.jtl reported 0.0% of errors [SUCCESS]. Build status is: SUCCESS
Finished: SUCCESS
```

See [How to Run Taurus with the Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-taurus-jenkins-performance-plugin) article for comprehensive information and instructions just in case.

Comment: It works for 9 of my scripts and this one it doesn't so I don't know what could be another reason for this to occur?